# How to show y axis values on line points in a morris line graph

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, graph, morris.js

I want to show a y-axis value on a line point in a Morris line graph. I was not able to make that work in Morris.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="line-example"></div>
</body>
```

**Script**

```
var morris = Morris.Line({
    element: 'line-example',
    data: data,
    xkey: 'date',
    ykeys: ['Data_Error','Data_Success'],
    labels: ['Data_Error','Data_Success'],
    colors: ['yellow',"blue","Green"],
    smooth:false,
    parseTime:false,
    hideHover:'auto'
});
```

[Current Working Graph in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ztbu8oo/64/)

[Expected sample Graph Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4e5f9.png)

How to implement this in Morris line graph?

Comment: please answer me if anyone have idea about this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, that would be a great feature. Unfortunately, this feature does not exists in the latest version of Morris.js (v.0.5.1).

You can try to modify Morris to add this feature, but this will be not be easy to achieve.